# Example of a subspace S of a Hilbert space such that S^(⊥⊥) does not equal S?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

I try to find an example of a subspace S of a Hilbert space H such that S^(⊥⊥) does not equal S. I know that subspace cannot be closed as for closed subspaces S^(⊥⊥)=S holds true.

Does there exist such a subspace? What would be a specific example or a way to construct one?

Comment: Shouldn't the inclusion go the other way, $S \subset (S^{\perp})^{\perp}$?

Comment: I know that " if s is a closed subspace of H, then S^(⊥⊥)=S." I need to the example to show that for not closed sub space of H S^(⊥⊥)≠S.

Comment: If you want to give an example where the orthogonal complement of the orthogonal complement is strictly greater than the original (non-closed) subspace $S$, think about the extreme:  $S$ is a dense (but not-closed) subspace of $H$.  Do the computation.

Comment: For a subspace $S$ of a Hilbert space, $S^{\perp\perp}$ is the closure of $S$. So ...

Answer (score 2):

For an explicit example take $H=\ell^2$ and $S=\operatorname{span}\{(x_n):x_i = 1,\ x_j=0,\ i\neq j\}$.
As is well known, $\bar{S} = H$, and since $(1/n)\notin S$, but $(1/n)\in H$,
$S\neq H = \bar{S}$, i.e. $S$ cannot be closed. Now use the fact that $(S^\bot)^\bot = \bar{S}$.